# What does the Dragon Egg do?

Tags: hack-slash-loot

I recently found a Dragon Egg while playing *Hack,Slash,Loot*, specifically in the Dwell in the Deep story arc.

It appears to be an item that I can equip in my off-hand slot, but I can't seem to find any use for said egg. It doesn't appear to give any sort of bonuses to my character, either. I'm at a loss as to what to do with it!

**What do I do with this dragon egg?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I emailed the creator - David Williamson - and this was his reply:

> Hi Jarrod,
>
> It boosts your magic strength, and gives resistance to fire and
>   vulnerability to silver. The amount it increases your magic depends on
>   the level you found the egg; level 1 = magic +4/+2, 2 = +6/+3, 3 =
>   +8/+4, 4 = +10/+5, 5 = +12/+6.
>
> I hope that answers your question.